# What does Java's type parameter wildcard really mean? What's the real difference between Foo and Foo<?>?

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee, types

For a generic interface:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    void f(T t); 
}
```

The difference between the two fields:

```
public class Bar {
    Foo foo1; 
    Foo<?> foo2; 
}
```

Is that `foo2` is a generic Type and `foo`is not. Since `?` is a wildcard (which I think means any type) and every type is a sub-type of Object, then I wold expect `Foo<?>` and `Foo<Object>` to semantically and syntactically equivalent.

However, check out the following:

```
public class Puzzler {
    void f() {
        Integer i = null; 
        Foo<?> foo1 = null;
        foo1.foo(i); // ERROR 
        Foo foo2 = null; 
        foo2.foo(i); // OKAY
        Foo<Integer> foo3 = null; 
        foo3.foo(i); // OKAY 
        Foo<Object> foo4 = null; 
        foo4.foo(i); // OKAY
    }

    private interface Foo<T> {
        void foo(T t);
    } 
}
```

So `Foo<?>` and `Foo<Object>` are **not** the same syntactically.

What's going on here? I'm pretty stuck in trying to understand this.

Comment: assuming these are compilation errors?

Comment: @andrewcooke That code would be valid; however, since the object would be stored in a `Foo<?>` variable, it wouldn't know about the `String` parameter. Consequently, if `Foo` has any methods that take arguments of type `T`, the only allowed value would be `null`, and if it has any methods that return `T`, it is treated as `Object`.

Comment: sorry, deleted my comment before i saw your reply.  am now confused.  when does capture work?

Comment: oh, ok, capture only matches exactly with itself.  it's obvious now i see the compiler error in some test code...

Answer (score 6):

`Foo<?>` is semantically the same as `Foo<? extends Object>`: it is a `Foo` with type parameter of something specific, but the only thing known about "something" is that it is some subclass of `Object` (which isn't saying too much, since all classes are subclasses of `Object`). `Foo<Object>`, on the other hand, is a `Foo` with type parameter specifically `Object`. While everything is assignment-compatible with `Object`, not everything will be assignment-compatible with `?` where `?` extends `Object`.

Here's an example of why `Foo<?>` should generate an error:

```
public class StringFoo implements Foo<String> {
    void foo(String t) { . . . }
}
```

Now change your example to this:

```
Foo<?> foo1 = new StringFoo();
```

Since `i` is an `Integer`, there's no way that the compiler should allow `foo1.foo(i)` to compile.

Note that

```
Foo<Object> foo4 = new StringFoo();
```

will also not compile according to the rules for [matching parameterized types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.5) since `Object` and `String` are provably distinct types.

`Foo` (without type parameter at all—a raw type) should usually be considered a programming error. According to the [Java Language Specification (§4.8)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8), however, the compiler accepts such code in order to not break non-generic, legacy code.

Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), none of this makes any difference to generated the byte code. That is, the only differences between these are at compile time.

Comment: Compilers *can't* treat raw types as errors, see [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

Comment: @Daniel - In Eclipse, you can set the compiler to treat the use of raw types as errors. You can also set most compilers to treat all warnings as errors and compilers can certainly warn about the use of raw types.

Comment: To elaborate: If you use `Foo` as a _raw type_ (that is, without a type parameter), this will (a) generate a compile-time warning (which you can ignore), (b) cause the compiler to use `Object` for all generic types, and (c) prevent the compiler from checking the type parameters for correctness in the context of other generics. For instance, `Foo<String> f = new Foo<Object>();` is a compile-time error, but `Foo<String> f = new Foo();` will compile (with a warning) and then raise a `ClassCastException` at runtime if the types are wrong. This is undesirable, so don't use raw types.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these types:

- `List<Object>`
- `List<CharSequence>`
- `List<String>`

Even though `String` is a subtype of `CharSequence` which is a subtype of `Object`, these List types do not have any subtype-supertype relationships. (Curiously, `String[]` *is* a subtype of `CharSequence[]` which is a subtype of `Object[]`, but that's for historical reasons.)

Suppose we want to write a method which prints a List. If we do

```
void print(List<Object> list) {...}
```

this will not be able to print a `List<String>` (without hacks), since a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`. But with wildcards, we can write

```
void print(List<?> list) {...}
```

and pass it any List.

Wildcards can have upper and lower bounds for added flexibility. Say we want to print a list which contains only `CharSequence`s. If we do

```
void print(List<CharSequence> list) {...}
```

then we encounter the same problem -- we can only pass it a `List<CharSequence>`, and our `List<String>` is not a `List<CharSequence>`. But if we instead do

```
void print(List<? extends CharSequence> list) {...}
```

Then we can pass this a `List<String>`, and a `List<StringBuilder>`, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Well, due to the type erasure, anything generics-related is compile-time only; I guess that's what you are calling syntactical.
I think your initial assessment is correct and real difference is that  makes it a generic-typed variable and plain Foo doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Object is the supertype of all types in java. However, Foo is not the supertype of all Foo. The supertype of all Foo is Foo. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard in `Foo<?>` indicates that within the current scope, you don't know or care what type of 'Foo' you have.

`Foo<?>` and `Foo<? extends Object>` are the same (the first is shorthand for the other). `Foo<Object>` is different.

***A concrete example***:

You can assign any sort of `List` to `List<?>`
e.g.

```
List<?> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<?> list3 = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
```

If you have a `List<?>` you can call `size()` because you don't need to know what type of list it is to find out its size. And you can call `get(i)` because we know that the list contains some sort of `Object`, so the compiler will treat it as if `get` returns and `Object`.
But you can't call `add(o)` because you don't know (and the compiler doesn't know) what sort of list you're dealing with.
In our example above you wouldn't want to allow `list1.add(new Object());` because that's supposed to be a list of `String`s

The reason for wildcards is so you can do things like this:

```
public static boolean containsNull(List<?> list)
{
    for(Object o : list )
    {
       if( o == null ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That code can work on any sort of list that you want, a `List<String>`, `List<Object>`, `List<Integer>`, etc.

If the signature was `public static boolean containsNull(List<Object> list)` then you could only pass `List<Object>` to it, `List<String>` wouldn't work.